# How to access custom cell created in xib

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have designed a custom cell in xib. And created a class for that as well. The code for that class is as given below-

```
class ProjectsCell : UITableViewCell {    
@IBOutlet var projectNameLabel: UILabel!  //This is outlet to which I will assign value.
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

Now I have a view controller there I am trying to access this cell. In storyboard I have given reusable identifier "Cell". Now I am using this cell like the following code-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ProjectsCell
        let project = projects[indexPath.row]
        cell.projectNameLabel?.text = project.ProjectName //********* Here I am getting exception for projectNameLabel. 
        return cell
```

I think that label is coming null. I have tried the following approach also but that is also not working.

```
var cell: ProjectsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as ProjectsCell
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ProjectsCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as ProjectsCell
```

What can be the issue if anyone has faced this same issue.

Comment: Put the code registering cell in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Currently am not doing anything for that..

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `class ProjectsCell: UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Have you connected the .nib and .h ?

Comment: Yeah.. I forgot to type that in the question. That I have already done.. But nothing happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following code-

```
var array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ProjectsCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        var cell = array[0] as ProjectsCell
        let project = projects[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel?.text = project.Name
        return cell
```

Thanks everyone for contributing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your custom cell should inherit from the class UITableViewCell. So the class would look like this.

```
class ProjectsCell: UITableViewCell {    
 @IBOutlet var projectNameLabel: UILabel!  //This is outlet to which I will assign value.
 override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  // Initialization code
 }

 override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
 super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

 // Configure the view for the selected state
 }
}
```

If you have it like this it should work. Because i am doing it like that in my Apps. For the future if you create a class you can use the 'File -> New Files...' menu. There you can select coca touch class and specify the class you want to inherit from and xcode will add all necessary functions.

Comment: Also the nib needs to be registered in the viewDidLoad method (well, anywhere but the cellForRow method).

Answer (score 0):

You have dequeued the custom cell but not initialised it with the following method.
Besides this you also have to set your custom class as the sub-class of UITableViewCell this is because you are getting the null value for the cell.

```
if cell == nil {
cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStylePlain reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it set the dataSource and delegate :
[image: It can work]
<sub>(source: [icodeblog.com](http://www.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/datasourceconnection1.png))</sub>